# C++ OOP Basics - Returning an object reference properly?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning C++ and have a problem working with an object returned as a reference which I want to continue to use and modify.

I have two classes, University and Student.

University is instantiated and has method addStudent() which stores a new Student object in a private vector data member of University. I want the method to return a reference to the newly created Student object. I then want to call the Student::addCourse() method on the returend object to add some courses to the student's "transcript."

I thought that since I returned a reference to the Student object it would update itself stored in the _Students vector in the University object, and therefore the changes would be visible outside its scope, but it doesn't keep the changes.

When I call printTranscript() on the returned Student object, it properly shows the added courses.

But, when I call printRegistrar() on the University object, it shows that student has no courses.

This seems like I'm missing a fundamental OOP principle. What am I doing wrong, and how do I make it work?

(I already have this working using a student ID as a handle to reference a student between objects, but I thought this way seemed more elegant, if I could get it to work.)

The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/cjmC1UuL

```
// Create a new university called UHD.
University UHD;

// Add 4 students to UHD.
UHD.addStudent("Jim");
UHD.addStudent("Bill"); 
Student Bob = UHD.addStudent("Bob");
UHD.addStudent("Greg");

// Add 3 classes for Bob
Bob.addCourse("WRTG140");
Bob.addCourse("MATH009");
Bob.addCourse("BIOL101");       


// Shows Bob correctly has 3 classes.
Bob.printTranscript();

// BUG?: Shows Bob incorrectly has 0 classes.
UHD.printRegistrar();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UHD.addStudent("Bob")
```

The result of this expression is indeed a reference to the internal `Student` object.

```
Student Bob = UHD.addStudent("Bob");
```

Here, however, you are copying from that reference to construct the object `Bob`. If you want to continue to keep a reference, you need to make `Bob` a reference:

```
Student& Bob = UHD.addStudent("Bob");
```

Note, however, that `Bob` may not remain a valid reference for long. At most you can expect it to last until the `UHD` object is around, but adding new students may cause the vector to reallocate its elements, in which case the reference is no longer referring to a valid object. As @tenfour suggests in the comments, a `std::list` would avoid that problem because it does not reallocate its elements. However, I would suggest that leaking references to your internal objects is a bad way to do things anyway, and would instead suggest having a way of modifying the internal `Student` objects through the `University` interface (perhaps just a simple setter).

Comment: It's also not safe to keep this reference for long; I think `list` is a better option so the reference never moves

Comment: @tenfour Yeah. In fact, they may already have that problem, because they're adding another `Student` after adding the one they keep a reference to.

Comment: A weekend lost to one character. Awesome. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Student Bob = UHD.addStudent("Bob");
```

This call triggers the copy constructor, and hence returns a copy of "Bob", but not the actual object you added to UHD.